# Argument Type 'AnyObject' does not conform to expected type NSCopying

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I am trying to use `NSDictionary` in `Swift` and I am facing the above-mentioned problem. I have a dictionary of the following format:

```
let xyz: NSMutableDictionary = ["1":[1,2,3,4,"1","n","1","2"],"2":[1,2,3,4,"+","o","6","2"]]
```

I want to iterate over keys in the dictionary and extract the 6th element of the array. I tried the following; but did not meet with any luck:

```
for keys in dictKeyMutableDict {
    let xCentVal = xyz[keys as! [NSCopying]][6]
}
```

I keep on receiving a subscript error and if I remove `as! [NSCopying]`, I receive the above error. Does anyone know how to deal with such case?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by using `NSCopying`?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `NSMutableDictionary` and make it mutable by make it a var. Now you can remove the `as! [NSCopying]`

```
var xyz = ["1":[1,2,3,4,"1","n","1","2"],"2":[1,2,3,4,"+","o","6","2"]]

for keys in dictKeyMutableDict {
    let xCentVal = xyz[keys]![6]
}
```

Or better optional unwrap it:

```
for keys in dictKeyMutableDict {
    if let v = xyz[keys] {
        let xCentVal = v[6]
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to use NSMutableDictionary since I will be passing it to Objective C to read it. It apparently can read NSDictionary only.