# Argument type 'Int' does not conform to expected type 'NSCoding & NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol'

Tags: swift, researchkit

I am new to Swift and was trying some tutorials to learn and polish my knowledge on Swift. I stumbled upon above error in this code which I didn't understand. In case anyone of you have idea, please explain whats wrong here.

```
    let textChoices =   [
    ORKTextChoice(text: "Create a ResearchKit app", value:0),
    ORKTextChoice(text: "Seek the Holy grail", value:1),
    ORKTextChoice(text: "Find a shrubbery", value:2)
]
```

I resolved the error by suggestion provided by Xcode and now my code looks like

```
    let textChoices =   [
    ORKTextChoice(text: "Create a ResearchKit app", value:0 as NSCoding & NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol),
    ORKTextChoice(text: "Seek the Holy grail", value:1 as NSCoding & NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol),
    ORKTextChoice(text: "Find a shrubbery", value:2 as NSCoding & NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol)
]
```

There is another solution I got from [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36583232/argument-type-anyobject-does-not-conform-to-expected-type-nscopying). While it works, I am still not clear about the problem and solution. What is the concept I am missing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As `ORKTextChoice`'s initialiser has an abstract parameter type for `value:`, Swift will fallback on interpreting the integer literals passed to it as `Int` – which does not conform to `NSCoding`, `NSCopying` or `NSObjectProtocol`. It's Objective-C counterpart, `NSNumber`, however does.

Although, rather than casting to `NSCoding & NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol`, which would result in a bridge to `NSNumber` (albeit an indirect and unclear one), you can simply make this bridge directly:

```
let textChoices = [
    ORKTextChoice(text: "Create a ResearchKit app", value: 0 as NSNumber),
    ORKTextChoice(text: "Seek the Holy grail", value: 1 as NSNumber),
    ORKTextChoice(text: "Find a shrubbery", value: 2 as NSNumber)
]
```

Your original code would have worked prior to Swift 3, as Swift types were able to be implicitly bridged to their Objective-C counterparts. However, as per [SE-0072: Fully eliminate implicit bridging conversions from Swift](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0072-eliminate-implicit-bridging-conversions.md), this is no longer the case. You need to make the bridge explicit with `as`.